# php email multiple recipients

Tags: php, email

I am trying to to loop through a select drop-down menu and send an email to multiple recipients. Every time I add a comma to add multiple emails the form fails.
Here are the chunks of code I am working with, but I would like to add more email address for 'recipient_1' 2 and 3 separated by a comma.

```
$recipients = array(
'recipient_1' => 'example1@email.com,
'recipient_2' => 'example2@email.com',
'recipient_3' => 'example3@email.com'
);


$to = $recipients[$_REQUEST['recipient']];


 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);



<select name="recipient" id="location" tabindex="20">
        <option value="-1">--- Please Select ---</option>
        <option value="recipient_1">City 1</option>
        <option value="recipient_2">City 2</option>
        <option value="recipient_3">City 3</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: In your array you're missing '' around example1@email.com, for starters. Maybe just copy-paste thing...

Comment: That was actually just an error copying and pasting onto this site, I do have the single quote in my code after example1@email.com

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing quote after the first `recipient_1`:

```
'recipient_1' => 'example1@email.com,
                                    ^--here
```

that'd cause a syntax error.

Comment: That was actually just an error copying and pasting onto this site, I do have the single quote in my code after example1@email.com

Comment: IN that case, show the chunk of code where you loop over the recipients, as the rest of the code you've shown is useless for debugging.

Comment: That's what the array does, that's all of the code. It works fine on a single recipient for example1@email.com 2, and 3. But fails when I try to do this..'recipient_1' => 'example1@email.com,example2@email.com,' and so on.

Comment: Ah. ok. Gotcha. Can you tell where the failure is? Is `mail()` returning FALSE (e.g. rejected by the system MTA), or is it being rejected farther down the line (delivery attempt? check mail server logs).

Answer (score 0):

i had created this kind of things using javascript.. take a look at my example [here](http://blog.softboxkid.com/code/trim.zip)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.